# After issuing an Insert using NewId() can you get the Ids that were used in that Insert

Tags: insert, sybase

I would like to know if it is possible to get the last inserted ID's from an Insert with Select NewId()?

Comment: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: Will this return multple IDS?

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() is mainly to get the newly inserted Id.